# LWJGL quad drawn from a button press disappearing

Tags: java, opengl, mouse, lwjgl

I am trying to draw a quad on click. Everytime I click on the screen, the quad flashes on the screen then disappears. If I keep clicking, it keeps flashing. Is it because of the order I am starting my methods? Thanks!

Edited with update code... I get the square to appear on click, but it will not stay. It follows the mouse across the screen

```
package main;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

import static helper.Artist.*;
import helper.Artist.*;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

public class GameWindow {
    public TiledMap map;
    public TiledMap menu;
    private int sx,sy;
    public int x,y;
    public static int fx;
    public static int fy;
    public int fxy;
    public boolean place = true;
public static enum states{

        MAIN, GAME; }

    public states state = states.MAIN;




    public void render(){
        switch(state){
        case MAIN:


            try {
                init();
                update();
                menu.render(0, 0);
            } catch (SlickException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case GAME:
            try {
                map = new TiledMap("res/map.tmx");
                map.render(0,0);
                Draw();
                if(place == false){
                    Quad();

                }

                update();
                //Draw();
                System.out.println(place);

                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                    glVertex2i(x*64,y*64);
                    glVertex2i(x * 64 + 64, y*64);
                    glVertex2i(x*64 + 64,y*64 + 64);
                    glVertex2i(x*64,y*64 + 64);
                glEnd();

            } catch (SlickException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }


    }


    public void Draw(){
        fx = this.fx;
        fy = this.fy;

        while(Mouse.next()){
            if(Mouse.getEventButtonState()){
                if(Mouse.getEventButton() == 0){
                System.out.println("Click");
                int iy = Mouse.getY();
                 fy = (iy+0x20)>>0x06;

                int ix = Mouse.getX();
                 fx = (ix+0x20)>>0x06;


                place = false;


            }else{

                place = true;
            }

        }} 



    }


    public void Quad(){

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2i(fx*64,fy*64);
        glVertex2i(fx * 64 + 64, fy*64);
        glVertex2i(fx*64 + 64,fy*64 + 64);
        glVertex2i(fx*64,fy*64 + 64);
    glEnd();
    }

    public void update(){




        int object = map.getLayerIndex("Tile Layer 2");

        //System.out.println(x);
        map.getTileId(0, 0, object);

        while(Keyboard.next()){

        if(Keyboard.getEventKeyState()){
            if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_DOWN){
            //System.out.println(y);
            if(map.getTileId(x , y+1, object) ==0){

                y++;
                //System.out.println(y);
            }

        }}
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)){
            System.out.println(y);
            if(y>=1){
                if(map.getTileId(x, y-1, object) ==0){

                    y--;
                System.out.println(y);

                }
            }
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
            System.out.println(x);
            if(map.getTileId(x -1, y, object) ==0){

                x--;
                System.out.println(x);
            }

        }


        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)){
            System.out.println(x);
            if(map.getTileId(x + 1,y, object) ==0){

                x++;
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }}
    }

    public void init() throws SlickException{
        menu = new TiledMap("res/menu.tmx");
        map = new TiledMap("res/map.tmx");
        x = 1;
        y = 0;


    }
    public void Mouse(){
        int iy = Mouse.getY();
         fy = (iy+0x20)>>0x06;

        int ix = Mouse.getX();
         fx = (ix+0x20)>>0x06;


        //System.out.println(fy);
        //System.out.println(fx);
    }
    public void checkInput(){
        switch(state){
        case MAIN:
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RETURN)){
                state = states.GAME;
            }

            break;
        case GAME:
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
                state = states.MAIN;
            }
        }

    }


    public GameWindow(){


        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1280,960));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Display.setTitle("Hello");

        //initialization
        grass = LoadTexture("dirt64");
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 1280, 960, 0, 1, -1 );
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            //render code
            checkInput();
            Mouse();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            render();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
    new GameWindow();

}}
```

Comment: think about how the control flows, the time you draw when you clicked is when the square is drawn but the next time you draw there is no click and you don't get into the while,

Comment: How can I fix this. Where should I move the method so it stays